# ASP.NET CustomValidator - is possible to change ClientValidationFunction on client side?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation, customvalidator

Is it possible to change ClientValidationFunction of ASP.NET CustomValidator on client side (from javascript)? I would like to select ClientValidationFunction dynamically in javascript, to perform conditional validation (ClientValidationFunction will be set to validator depending on actions, which user does on page).

Is this approach possible, and how?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I would call from my client validation function separate functions belonging to my specified condition.

```
function myVal(sender, args)
{
   if ( [condition 1] ) return func_cond1( sender, args );
   else return func_cond2( sender, args );
}
```